# .net core web api File randomly loads only part of the response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, filecontentresult

I am loading an image from S3 bucket as `byte[]` and send it as a response from my asp.net core 3.1 web API controller method.

Here is my code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(string documentId, int pageId)
    {
        var imageArray = await _documentService.GetImage(documentId, pageId);
        return File(imageArray, "image/png");
    }
```

It works to an extend. The Response is delivered to the client:

[image]

But the image itself is never fully loaded:

sometimes it loads just a little bit:

[image]

sometimes a bit more:

[image]

But never the full image. Looks like it interrupts for whatever reason and just sends whatever got into the initial buffer.

Comment: Check your response byte array. Is it the full bytestream? You need to figure out if it's a api or rendering issue.

Comment: Yes. You are right I was not reading correctly the stream from S3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Athanasios - the issue is not related to the File response.
I wasn't reading the S3 stream properly. The error has gone after fixing it.